# x Time within time frame (24h time format)

Tags: python, time, frame, strftime

Best practice to get if a time within a given time frame.

**Current hour**: 22:00
**Timeframes** (start, end time of shifts):

```
00:00 - 08:00
04:00 - 12:00
08:00 - 16:00
12:00 - 20:00
16:00 - 00:00
20:00 - 04:00
```

Using the logic:

```
if currentHour >= startHour and currentHour <= endHour:
    ...
```

Doesn't really work since it will not be less then 04:00 if the time is 22:00.
Using OR will not work either since then 22 will be more then 00:00 and that's not right.

Argh I don't know if it's the lack of caffeine or what but i just can't wrap my head around it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remember that, if the endHour < startHour, it's actually on a different day, ie. 24 hours later than it says. Likewise, for an hour to be in this range, it could be on either day, so if it's < startHour, it could be on the next day.

```
if currentHour < startHour:
   currentHour += 24
if endHour < startHour:
   endHour += 24

if currentHour >= startHour and currentHour <= endHour:
   //...code
```

Comment: Care to explain why you're adding +24 to currentHour, if the hour is 23 that would make it 47?!?

Comment: To signal that the current hour (and also possibly startHour) are actually on the next day

Comment: Tried it, works now at least (23:34), gotta love stackoverflow and it's brains! I'm tired and i just tangled in my brain on this one, thank you Jacob, works perfectly so far!

Answer (score 0):

If 00:00 is the end of timeframe, make it 24:00. This would solve make your `if` statement work in the expected manner.

**My Bad** : do this

`if currentHour >= startHour and currentHour <= endHour or currentHour <= startHour and currentHour >= endHour :`

Edit: This generates the following,

```
print cur, start, end, logic1, logic2
23 8 0 False False
23 20 12 False False
23 0 20 False False
23 12 4 False False
23 8 16 False False
23 16 8 False False
```

Comment: it doesn't handle 04:00, though

Comment: But it isn't.  OP's using `20:00 - 4:00`.  (I believe those are columns of `starttime endtime`)

Comment: Your logic is close, but no cigar i'm afraid, tried it and it didn't stick for some reason :/
Most likely because the second logic can't be true, ever, i think..
Since it will only be true on either side of the AND statement.